# Multiple If ElseIf NOT WORKING IN CSHTML

Tags: razor

The first IF and last ElseIf statements are working. But not the second If statement.
please help.

```
<div>
  @if(string.Equals(code,"CI"))
  {
    <img src="~/Images/CI.jpg" style="float:right" height=208" width="268px"/>
  }

  **else if(string.Equals(code,"NY"))**
    {
    <img src="~/Images/NY.jpg" style="float:right" height="208" width="268px"/>
    }

  else if (string.Equals(code, "KY"))
      {
        <img src="~/Images/KY.JPG" style="float:right" height="208" width="268px"/>  
      }


</div>
```

Comment: ... put a space in between the `else` and `if`?

Comment: i did and still not working!!! The { of the first IF ends after the second else if. i Dont understand

Comment: The if else statement shown in ** ** is not working. 
The parentheses of the first IF { ends at the second if's parentheses}

Comment: Did you notice that your `height` field in your first `img` tag if your `if` statement is missing a `"`?

Comment: Thanks man!!! It worked !!! This site is awesome!!

Comment: Ohk..How to do that!! I clicked on the big tick if thats what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already corrected the `else if` blunder as noted in my comment to you (as well as from Syed shown here), it could be the fact that you are missing a `"` character in your first `<img>` tag where you are specifying the `height` field.  Specifically:

```
  @if(string.Equals(code,"CI"))
  {
    <img src="~/Images/CI.jpg" style="float:right" height=208" width="268px"/>
  }
```

Try closing the quotations in your `height` field.  As such:

```
  @if(string.Equals(code,"CI"))
  {
    <img src="~/Images/CI.jpg" style="float:right" height="208" width="268px"/>
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use a space between elseif in 2nd elseif, write ( `else if { }` )